# Bought a new hdmi cable to connect my PC to my TV - no display detected

Tags: hdmi, cable

After I've connected the cable to both ends my nVidia control panel still doesn't recognize the 2nd display which is a Skyworth LCD with a perfectly fine regular HDMI input.

I have the newest graphic card driver installed.

What to do?

Comment: We need specifics.

Comment: Hi idan! You have to register here on the site and create an account. Then you can comment on answers, edit your question to include more info, et cetera. If you stay unregistered, you might lose your login.

Comment: My nvidia card needs to go through a boot sequence with the TV attached and powered on before it recognises it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a laptop, make sure the video output is configured.  Usually you can find a key which looks like a monitor symbol in the function keys, mine is F4.  Hold the down function key (by the start key) + press F4, then you should be able to select the display output.  This may varies from between laptops depending on manufacturer (mine is Hewlett Packard).

Also the TV must be set to receive from the HDMI port which you have connected the cable to.